# Is there a way to stop timers from firing in Node when in debug mode?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, settimeout, setinterval

I do Node debugging through VS Code, which is mostly an enjoyable experience, except when the script being debugged contains timers (triggered through `setTimeout()`, `setImmediate()` or `setInterval()`.

It appears even if you are in debug mode, the timers fire when they need to, and the program often fails when it should not (e.g., if the timer is checking for a service to be up and the service in question is paused in its execution in a debug session).

I recollect in C# world, there used to be a way to pause timers in debug mode and Visual Studio used to automatically take care of it. I want to know if something similar is available for Node debugging, with or without VS Code.

Note that the code in question is a server side script written in JavaScript, with no shims or presets involved. `Node` version is `10.0.0`. `NPM` version is `6.2.0`

Comment: If the timer is outside your program and it's checking to see if your program is alive and your program is stopped at a breakpoint, then you're just stuck.  When your program is stopped at a breakpoint, it's stopped.  It can't respond to outside queries or requests.  I see this all the time when debugging socket.io servers.  The socket.io client thinks the server has gone down when it's at a breakpoint (even using the debugger that comes with node.js) so it attempts to reconnect.  The only way I know of to avoid this is to debug with `console.log()` statements, not breakpoints.

Comment: A rather ugly solution is to add a piece of code that checks whether you're in debugging mode and overrides these functions (ie. `const originalSetTimeout = setTimeout; setTimeout = function (...args) { if (somehowCheckIfCurrentModuleBelongsToYourCode) { /* do nothing /* } else { setTimeout.apply(this, ...args) } }`

Comment: @farjad and jfriend00 thank you both for your comments. The timers are in a third party library that, ideally, I don't want to edit. It appears there might be no other option.I guess one could always clone a copy to mess with and revert to the unmolested version when done. Both are valid answers I guess. I'll leave this open for a few more days to let others comment as well.

Comment: @cod.ie I just noticed a little mistake in my example, you have to call `originalSetTimeout` within the function (instead of `setTimeout`). And taking your last comment into account, instead of checking if `setTimeout` is being called from your code, you'll have to figure out a way to check if it is actually called from the third party library. You might be better off modifying the library temporarily.